# Navigate to a package (external) R source code in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

As far as I know the R source code of an installed package is not available directly inside the library (directory) where it's installed. Instead there are (in the corresponding `R/` directory) binary files of the form `package.rdb` and `package.rdx` with the R code compiled (I haven't found much information about them or their format, named *compact package file format* [1](http://_https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-July/075948.html)).

Also, I haven't found a way to install the package including its original R source code (used to generate the compiled binary), in a manner similar to Python's “Development Mode" [2](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode) (another question [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931230/install-package-in-development-mode-with-r-source-not-compiled-into-rdb) about this issue seems to corroborate this), where the source code of the package is directly available for inspection.

Some of the advantages (at least for me) of having the source code readily available as in Python's “Development Mode" are:

1. Any modification to the package source code is directly reflected in the calls to its functions, without requiring an explicit build or install after the modification.
2. IDEs (such as PyCharm) allow to easily navigate directly to a function definition inside the package, making it easy to inspect and modify it.

The first point is not that big of an issue thanks to Hadley's `devtools` [4](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) package, which allows to reload a modified package (through the `load_all` [5](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2556_4e9f1c2af93b4683a19e2303a52bb2d5.html) function) in a straightforward way. But the second point is the one I'm having trouble with.

RStudio provides a way to navigate to a function definition [6](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200710523-Navigating-Code) even for functions inside installed packages, but what it shows is only a read-only version of (what I assume is) the decompiled R code of the installed binary. Although it's very useful it still has some drawbacks, due to the fact that what is being displayed is not the actual R source code file that defined the function:

1. The code being showed has a restricted scope to the specific function, without showing the file where it's contained (nor the other functions surrounding it), which makes it harder to find the original file (which is not named in this view) inside the package source code where the function is defined (having to use more indirect methods such as `grep`).
2. The definition can't be modified for development purposes (to inspect it and understand how it works).
3. The comments of the original source file are not available, which makes the code much harder to understand (this, to me, is not a minor point).

I've read that RStudio indexes files from the current active project, so it might be possible (I haven't tried) to open a specific package as an RStudio project to index its R source files and be able to navigate to them when looking for a function definition, but that would still be a solution for a specific package, one at a time.

Is there a way indicate to RStudio where the original R source files are located for a specific installed package, to make them visible to its index, and being able to navigate to their function definitions?

I'm even open to being pointed to the RStudio source code (by someone familiarized and experienced with its code base) that handles the code navigation feature, to study a possible solution (or at least a temporal modification that would work for specific cases).

(There is a different question [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677435/efficient-and-recursive-way-to-navigate-through-r-code-on-rstudio) which states the same basic problem as this one, asking for a solution not restricted to RStudio, as a satisfactory question was not provided, I restrict this one specifically to RStudio, to see if a more concrete solution can be found).

[1]: _[https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-July/075948.html](http://_https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-July/075948.html)

[2]: _https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode

[3]: _[Install package in development mode (with R source not compiled into Rdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931230/install-package-in-development-mode-with-r-source-not-compiled-into-rdb)

[4]: _https://github.com/hadley/devtools

[5]: _http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2556_4e9f1c2af93b4683a19e2303a52bb2d5.html

[6]: _https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200710523-Navigating-Code

[7]: _[Efficient and recursive way to navigate through R code on Rstudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677435/efficient-and-recursive-way-to-navigate-through-r-code-on-rstudio)

EDIT: Regrettably I can't post more than two links because I'm new and lack the reputation, so until (and if) I get some reputation, most links will be missing, sorry about that.

EDIT: I'm confirming that an open an existing package with its R source code as an RStudio project (`File -> New Project -> Existing directory -> <package_dir>`) adds the source files (inside the `R/` directory) to the RStudio index and makes them available to navigate to them when browsing for a function definition. Also, as a partial (and dirty) solution, R source files from other projects can be copied to the same directory and RStudio will (generally) also recognize them.

Comment: It's an interesting question. It's mostly fairly easy to see what R will run if you type the function without parentheses, and what's in a package's namespace (e.g. `ls(envir = asNamespace('utils'))`), but not so easy to see the original source and how it was structured. The easiest option for that is honestly GitHub, and if a package isn't hosted there, [MetaCRAN](https://github.com/cran). That's pretty obviously not what you were after, though, so...build it?

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for the comment, I wasn't clear enough in the question (and should fix that), but in this scenario it is assumed that I already have available the package with the source code in a local directory, but instead of manually browsing it (or with `grep`) I would like to be able to directly navigate to the function definition I want without knowing a priori where it is located inside the package R source code structure. If your question is suggesting to build the feature, I would be open to it, but need to know more of RStudio's source (and maybe I should ask that somewhere else).

Comment: Right. The short answer is that the functionality isn't built, because R references the built package, not the source, and package structure is flexible enough that you can't say from the built source what file/line number it came from (unless there's logging in the build that I'm unaware of). Even if you made your own build system with suitable logging, it's still hard, because within the package there will be internal functions, calls to functions in other packages or languages, etc. It's possible, but hard.